# jQuery UI Draggable and Slider Axis X

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-slider

There is my problem: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMXLj/143/)

```
$("#timeline").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: [-2110, 0, 0, 0]
});
```

I made the simple draggable image but i want to add a slider like this http://jqueryui.com/slider/#side-scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use javascript for this unless you want a custom scroll bar or to be able to drag with your mouse (a touch device would work just fine, though). You can get away with simply putting the image in a container and just setting `overflow: auto` on it.

http://jsfiddle.net/LMXLj/146/embedded/result/

If you want it to be draggable with a mouse, which isn't the most natural thing, you don't want to be using `.draggable()`. You would want to look into a plugin like [dragscroll](https://github.com/iwyg/jquery.dragscroll).